# How to configure DNS record on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I have a domain with Google, and I want to configure DNS on Google Cloud to use "www.example.com", and not "sites.google.com/...."

Comment: I would recommend to add more details to your post as it is too vague, what service did you use or where are you hosting? Based on your current post, this [official guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7392423?hl=en) might help.

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution here is to use any of the following:

- CNAME record that points domainname.com  to domainname.provider.com
- A record that points domainname.com to the same IP address that domainname.provider.com

This should work for several different providers. But many providers use 'virtual hosting' which means that a single server, identified by an IP address, will be serving different websites, and will use the domain name as sent by an HTTP header. You need to tell the provider, sites.google.com, that domainname.com is a valid name for the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure a CNAME Record, this is used in the DNS to create an alias from one domain name to another domain name:
Example:
[www.yourdomain.com](http://www.yourdomain.com)  CNAME yourdomain.com

You could need also an A Record to point your Ip address at your domain. The A record translate the human readable domain name to an IP address.
Example:
yourdomain.com. A192.162.101.100 .

If you already has the CNAME Record  you can go to the Google cloud console  and select  the Cloud DNS page, once there you can follow the next steps:

1. Click the zone for which you want to create a resource record set.
2. On the Zone details page, click Add record set.
3. Enter the DNS name for the record set—for example, test.example.com.
4. Select the resource record type. (here you can chose the CNAME record)
5. Enter the time to live (TTL) for the resource record set—for example, 30
6. Select the TTL unit—for example, minutes.
7. Enter the details based on the record type that you have selected.
8. Click Create.

In the next [link](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/records?hl=en#record_type) you can find more information related to manage record